# How to loop to create another array with two elements when they are repeated in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, web-scraping

I want to create a two-dimensional array from another existent array, which is scraped from a website through document.querySelectorAll(). I want to add from two to two depending on the elements of the array. Let me show you an example to make me more understandable.

```
myArray = ["price $33", "extra $2", "price $54", "price $20", "extra $3.5", "price $25", "extra $2", "price $31"]
```

In theory, every two elements are paired (the strings with "extra" are related with the strings with "price"). However, as you can see **there are prices that do not have extras**. Every extra comes with the previous price. I want to add the price and its extra together as well as the price alone. Like this:

```
new array = [["price $33", "extra $2"], ["price $54"], ["price $20", "extra $3.5"], ["price $25", "extra $2"], ["price $31"]]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: please add usable arrays. btw, what have you tried?

Comment: hello, I edited the question! sorry about that, I was in a hurry and I forgot to add the elements as strings! I'm trying to sort the array to have each "price" and "extra" element on the one hand, and "price" alone when it does not have an "extra". All this info comes from web scrapping, which I made an array from the data of a specific class. If it had the same pattern I wouldn't have any problem (like taking every two indexes), with a loop for example. But I need a way to detect when there are two "price" followed together, or something like that. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array and check if the string starts with `extra`, then push the the last array of add a new array with the string.

```js
var array = ["price $33", "extra $2", "price $54", "price $20", "extra $3.5", "price $25", "extra $2", "price $31"],
    result = array.reduce((r, s) => {
        if (s.startsWith('extra')) r[r.length - 1].push(s);
        else r.push([s]);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with clever use of `reduce` including a flag to say whether to skip the next element. Something like below:

```js
var myArray = ["price $33", "extra $2", "price $54", "price $20", "extra $3.5", "price $25", "extra $2", "price $31"];

var newArray = myArray.reduce( (agg, item, index, arr) => {
   if(agg.skipNext)
   {
      agg.skipNext = false;
      return agg;
   }
   if(index < arr.length-1 && arr[index+1].startsWith("extra"))
   {
      agg.skipNext = true;
      agg.push([item,arr[index+1]]);
   }
   else
      agg.push([item]);
   return agg;
},[]);

console.log(newArray);
```